# foldl definition possible wrong in SML/NJ 110.75

Tags: smlnj

The signature of foldl in SML/NJ 110.75 is

```
foldl;
val it = fn : ('a * 'b -> 'b) -> 'b -> 'a list -> 'b
```

Also if I give:

```
foldl (op -) 2 [1];
```

I will take as answer ~1 instead of 1

Can you confirm my findings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the basis library: http://www.standardml.org/Basis/list.html#SIG:LIST.foldl:VAL

> foldl f init [x1, x2, ..., xn]
>       returns
>
> ```
> f(xn,...,f(x2, f(x1, init))...)
>
> or init if the list is empty.
> ```

thus in `foldl (op -) 2 [1]` the result is the evaluation of `xn - init` or `1 - 2`

What makes this particular example a bit harder to understand is that `(op -)` is a non-associative infix operator. So the `f` in the basis library definition gets moved between `xn` and  `init`.

The signature is only for static type checking, and it is worth remembering that `'a` and `'b` may be of the same type.